# Limits Definition of the derivatives of Functions

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have a question that says:

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and the expression
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)}{2h}$$

It says to state the limit definition of the derivative $f'(a)$ and show that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}  =  f'(a)$$

Hint: Use the substitution $t=-h$.

How do I start this question off, as I was thinking that I would have to do first principals of the limits or do L'hopitals rule for finding the derivative of the limit.

Can anyone help, as I'm really stuck on how to approach and do this question?
Thanks.

Comment: Where does the first limit expression come into play?

Comment: It just gives me an expression which is 
lim (f(a+h)-f(a-h))/2h h->0
h->0
Then the question says the state the limit definition etc...

Comment: Yes, but the rest of your question does not reference that expression at all, so it's not clear how that is relevant.

Comment: I'm unsure too, this is why i'm really struggling with this question, as I'm unsure what the first expression has to do with any of the question, but still don't understand the question itself anyhow...

Comment: The usual limit definition of a derivative is $f'(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.  The question is asking you to show that the expression $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}$ is equivalent.  The first limit expression in your question is also equivalent.

Comment: Ok, what kind of theorem or workings out would i use to answer the question though?

Comment: Do as the question says.  Make the substitution $h=-t$, and that's basically it.  If you want to demonstrate the equivalence of the first limit expression, follow Abishanka's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)}{2h}=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)+f(a)-f(a-h)}{2h}=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{2h}+\frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{2h}$$

Comment: Thank you for this, i'm unclear though how [(f(a+h)−f(a))/2h+(f(a)−f(a−h))/2h] = f'(a).  Please may you help me understand this?

Comment: Both the terms $\rightarrow f'(a)/2$ as $h\rightarrow0$. From your question I thought you know the definition of derivative as a limit of this quotient.

Comment: The question is not clear to me . If f differentiable the limit of the above expression exists. If the limit of the above expression exists, is it differentiable?what is the question?